# Connecting to remote host via WinRM fails in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to run below provisioner using terraform on Windows VM

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type = "winrm"
      user     = "${local.admin_username}"
      password = "${local.admin_password}"
      port     = 5986
      https    = true
      timeout  = "10m"
      host = azurerm_public_ip.example.ip_address        
      insecure = true
    }

    inline = [
      "powershell.exe New-Item -Path c:\\ -Name testfile1.txt -ItemType file -Value This is a text string."
    ]
  }
```

While the VM is provisioned, I am facing error while trying to establish connection using remote-exec

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via WinRM...
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   Host: 52.172.xxx.xxx
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   Port: 5986
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   User: testadmin
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   Password: true
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   HTTPS: true
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   Insecure: true
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   NTLM: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.example (remote-exec):   CACert: false
azurerm_virtual_machine.example: Still creating... [11m50s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine.example: Still creating... [12m0s elapsed]


Error: timeout - last error: unknown error Post "https://52.172.xxx.xxx:5986/wsman": dial tcp 52.172.xxx.xxx:5986: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Is the provisioner provided in the right format?

Comment: Did you enable/configure WinRM and ICF (firewall) on the Windows host? By default, the WinRM service is installed and running but no listener is configured plus the Windows firewall will block connections to the WinRM ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WinRM to access Azure WM, we need to configure some things. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/winrm).

For example

1. Create a Key Vault

```
New-AzKeyVault -VaultName "<vault-name>" -ResourceGroupName "<rg-name>" -Location "<vault-location>" -EnabledForDeployment -EnabledForTemplateDeployment
```

2. Create a certificate

```
$certificateName = "somename"

$thumbprint = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $certificateName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -KeySpec KeyExchange).Thumbprint

$cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint)

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the certificate password." -AsSecureString

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\$certificateName.pfx" -Password $password
```

3. upload certificate to Azure key vault

```
$fileName = "<Path to the .pfx file>"
$fileContentBytes = Get-Content $fileName -Encoding Byte
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)

[System.Collections.HashTable]$TableForJSON = @{
    "data"     = $filecontentencoded;
    "dataType" = "pfx";
    "password" = "<password>";
}
[System.String]$JSONObject = $TableForJSON | ConvertTo-Json

$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $jsonEncoded -AsPlainText –Force
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<vault name>" -Name "<secret name>" -SecretValue $secret
```

4. Reference your self-signed certificates URL

```
"osProfile": {
      ...
      "secrets": [
        {
          "sourceVault": {
            "id": "<resource id of the Key Vault containing the secret>"
          },
          "vaultCertificates": [
            {
              "certificateUrl": "<URL for the certificate you got in Step 4>",
              "certificateStore": "<Name of the certificate store on the VM>"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "windowsConfiguration": {
        ...
        "winRM": {
          "listeners": [
            {
              "protocol": "http"
            },
            {
              "protocol": "https",
              "certificateUrl": "[reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', '<vault-name>', '<secret-name>'), '2015-06-01').secretUriWithVersion]"
            }
          ]
        },
        ...
      }
    },
```

5. Connect to Azure VM to enable winRm service

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

did you open up 5986 in the windows firewall and enable secure powershell? if not, then you need to use port 5985 and have https = false...besides insecure either going to false or being removed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).